# Unexpected assign inside a signal Godot

Tags: signals, game-development, godot

I need to assign a variable inside a signal, what I did is something like this:

`var cross_river = false`

`func _on_unlock_crossing_river_area_entered(area)`

`cross_river = true`

`pass`

but Godot always returns an "unexpected assign" error

how could I solve this problem???

Comment: @Theraot, hello, sorry the typo is in the question only, in the script I didn't forget about the ```:``` the error it sends is "unexpected assign" and sometimes it says "unexpected token if:"

Comment: Please fix the script in the question to match what you have.